# AES CTR implementation

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm trying to implement CTR mode by myself (only decryption for now), using only AES built-in functions from pycrypto. It means that I'm not supposed to use mode=AES.MODE_CTR. However, I know that using AES.MODE_CTR would be more simple, but I'm doing this as a learning experience.

I'm not sure about how to use AES as a PRF, in order to use it in a CTR cryptography algorithm.

What am I doing wrong?
(non-parallalel version)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

ciphers = ["69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b773304eec0ec7702330098ce7f7520d1cbbb20fc3" + \
    "88d1b0adb5054dbd7370849dbf0b88d393f252e764f1f5f7ad97ef79d59ce29f5f51eeca32eabedd9afa9329", \
    "770b80259ec33beb2561358a9f2dc617e46218c0a53cbeca695ae45faa8952aa" + \
    "0e311bde9d4e01726d3184c34451"]

key     = "36f18357be4dbd77f050515c73fcf9f2"  

class IVCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def increment(self):
        # Add the counter value to IV
        newIV = hex(int(self.value.encode('hex'), 16) + 1)

        # Cut the negligible part of the string
        self.value = newIV[2:len(newIV) - 1].decode('hex') # for not L strings remove $ - 1 $ 
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        self.increment()
        return self.value

    def string(self):
        return self.value

class CTR():
    def __init__(self, k):
        self.key = k

    def __strxor(self, a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
        if len(a) > len(b):
            return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
        else:
            return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

    def __split_len(self, seq, lenght):
        return [seq[i:i+lenght] for i in range(0, len(seq), lenght)]

    def __AESdecryptor(self, k, cipher):
        decryptor = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_ECB)

        return decryptor.decrypt(cipher)

    def decrypt(self, cipher):
        # Split the CT in blocks of 16 bytes
        blocks = self.__split_len(cipher.decode('hex'), 16)

        # Takes the initiator vector
        self.IV = IVCounter(blocks[0])
        blocks.remove(blocks[0])    

        # Message block 
        msg = []

        # Decrypt
        for b in blocks:
            aes = self.__AESdecryptor(self.key.decode('hex'), self.IV.string())
            msg.append(self.__strxor(b, aes))

            self.IV.increment()

        return ''.join(msg)

def main():
    decryptor = CTR(key)
    for c in ciphers:
        print 'msg = ' + decryptor.decrypt(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code was supposed to do the same that the code below, but it is not decoding as it should be.

```
import Crypto.Util.Counter
ctr_e = Crypto.Util.Counter.new(128, initial_value=long(IV.encode('hex'), 16))
decryptor = AES.new(key.decode('hex'), AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr_e)
print decryptor.decrypt(''.join(blocks))
```

Comment: yeah, it is. I'm sorry about that. I'll try codereview. Thx!

Comment: No problem, dasho, good luck getting your code to work.

Comment: I had put this question on code review, and the guys there put on hold the post and told me to put it on Stack Overflow. I'm a little bit confused, but I think that Code Review is only for working code.

Comment: @owlstead We can debug code here, provided the scope of the question is reasonable (which I'm not sure it is here).

Comment: @owlstead May I edit my question? I was thinking about "How to use AES as a pseudo-random function to use it in a CTR encryption algorithm?"

Comment: Hey, guys (@owlstead @Duncan). Thx for helping. I think I'm close to know where the problem is, and maybe It is the way I'm using the AES encryption (as pseudo-random function). I'm sorry about the confusing question. I've put this question here, because I had coded the CBC encryption in a very similar way, but I was not able do the same with CTR, as you can see.

Comment: Glad you've got it working, dasho!

Comment: By the way, AES is a Pseudo Random Permutation (PRP). It maps {0,1}^128 -> {0,1}^128 under a key. That is, its a permutation. All PRPs are PRFs (but PRFs are not PRPs because PRPs are efficient to invert or reverse). A good treatment is the Standford Crypto Course and the [lecture here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cs255/lectures/PRP-PRF.pdf). The Standford Crypto Course is online and free, if interested.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! Stanford Crypto Course is a very good course, and I'm already subscribbed in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Decrypt
for b in blocks:
    aes = self.__AESdecryptor(self.IV.string(), self.key.decode('hex'))
    msg.append(self.__strxor(b, aes))
    self.IV.increment()

return ''.join(msg)
```

AES CTR mode uses AES's forward transformation for both encryption and decryption. That is, in both cases, encrypt the counter and then perform the XOR. When I say the 'forward transformation', I mean you always perform `AES_Encrypt(counter)` (and never perform `AES_Decrypt(counter)`).

You perform the XOR on both the plain text and the cipher text, irregardless of whether you are encrypting or decrypting. `text XOR encrypt(counter)` is the encryption or decryption operation. That's a stream cipher.

`self.IV.string()` is not the AES key. Its the value that is encrypted under the key. Once encrypted, it is XOR'd with the {plain|cipher} text.

Comment: noloader, I'm sorry for I haven't understood your solution at the first time. I modified my code as you've told, and it works fine now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I've finally got this code working well, and the mistake was very simple. I shouldn't have used decrypt AES function, I should have used encrypt AES function (as noloader had said, and I'd not understood him very well at the first time). Thanks for everybody who helped and here is the fixed code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

ciphers = ["69dda8455c7dd4254bf353b773304eec0ec7702330098ce7f7520d1cbbb20fc3" + \
    "88d1b0adb5054dbd7370849dbf0b88d393f252e764f1f5f7ad97ef79d59ce29f5f51eeca32eabedd9afa9329",      \
    "770b80259ec33beb2561358a9f2dc617e46218c0a53cbeca695ae45faa8952aa" + \
    "0e311bde9d4e01726d3184c34451"]

key     = "36f18357be4dbd77f050515c73fcf9f2"  

class IVCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

    def increment(self):
        # Add the counter value to IV
        newIV = hex(int(self.value.encode('hex'), 16) + 1)

        # Cut the negligible part of the string
        self.value = newIV[2:len(newIV) - 1].decode('hex') # for not L strings remove $ - 1 $ 
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        self.increment()
        return self.value

    def string(self):
        return self.value

class CTR():
    def __init__(self, k):
        self.key = k.decode('hex')

    def __strxor(self, a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
        if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
        else:
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

    def __split_len(self, seq, lenght):
        return [seq[i:i+lenght] for i in range(0, len(seq), lenght)]

    def __AESencryptor(self, cipher):
        encryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        return encryptor.encrypt(cipher)

    def decrypt(self, cipher):
        # Split the CT into blocks of 16 bytes
        blocks = self.__split_len(cipher.decode('hex'), 16)

        # Takes the initiator vector
        self.IV = IVCounter(blocks[0])
        blocks.remove(blocks[0])    

        # Message block 
        msg = []

        # Decrypt
        for b in blocks:
        aes = self.__AESencryptor(self.IV.string())
        msg.append(self.__strxor(b, aes))

        self.IV.increment()

        return ''.join(msg)

def main():
    decryptor = CTR(key)
    for c in ciphers:
    print 'msg = ' + decryptor.decrypt(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```